# SQL Server: summarize results using max of other column

Tags: sql-server, summarize

I'm struggling with this one. I have the following data in the table (actually much more columns to be reduced to):

[image: Data example!]

The question is how do I get to the result?

The rules are that I only want just one row per subproduct taking only the `Max(changed)`.

Can you help me?

I tried `Group by Product, subproduct` but I failed miserably

HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following (change `Table1` to your table name):

```
select a.*
from Table1 a inner join
(
    select b.product, b.subproduct, max(b.changed) as mc
    from Table1 b
    group by b.product, b.subproduct
) c on 
a.product = c.product and 
a.subproduct = c.subproduct and 
a.changed = c.mc
```

The subquery selects the `Product` and `Subproduct` with the latest `Changed` value and the outermost query joins the original table with the record selected by the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Product, SubProduct ORDER BY Changed DESC) rn FROM table
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Product, SubProduct ORDER BY Changed DESC)` numbers the rows in descending order of Changed. Each time the Product+SubProduct combination changes, the numbering restarts from 1

Then we have an outer query that selects all the rows numbered with a 1

The reason why this works is because it's not really a group. The partition is kinda like a group but we don't lose any rows with this technique - all the rows in the input make it into the output with extra data added. In contrast, a group loses data; if you group up by product and subproduct you cannot add more columns without adding them to the grouping key, which destroys the group you're trying to create. The only other thing you can do with a column in a grouping query is run an aggregate function on it, but you can't say "get me the max Changed and i want the associated price" you can only ask for the max Changed, and the max price (or whatever) and they don't necessarily come from the same row

Comment: This is a great answer too, only thing I'd note is the current state of the question requires the ORDER BY to be on the "changed" column. But concept is solid.